Showing downloadable product links on success/thank you page after purchase
I'd like to show all downloadable product links on the success page after the customer (guest or logged) purchase.
Any ideas?

You can use this coded below in custom module which get downloadable product links successfully

app/code/Kam/Menu/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
<referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
    <block class="Kam\Menu\Block\Success"
           name="test.order.success"
           template="Kam_Menu::order/success.phtml"
           after="-">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>


Block file app/code/Kam/Menu/Block/Success.php
<?php
    namespace Kam\Menu\Block;

    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;


    class Success extends Template
    {
        protected $order;
        protected $checkoutSession;

        public function __construct(
            Template\Context $context,
            Order $order,
            CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->order = $order;
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        public function getDownloadableLinks()
        {
            $incrementId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();

            $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

            $items = $order->getAllItems();
            $downloadableLinks = [];

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($item->getProductType() == 'downloadable') {
                    $productId = $item->getProductId();
                    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

                    // Get the downloadable links associated with the product
                    $extensionAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
                    $links = $extensionAttributes->getDownloadableProductLinks();

                    foreach ($links as $item) {
                        $downloadableLinks[] = $item->getData();
                    }
            }

            return $downloadableLinks;
        }
    }
    }


app/code/Kam/Menu/view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml
<?php
$downloadableLinks = $block->getDownloadableLinks();

if (!empty($downloadableLinks)): ?>
    <h2><?php echo __('Your Downloadable Products'); ?></h2>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($downloadableLinks as $link): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $link['link_url']; ?>"><?php echo $link['link_url']; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>



result will be :


Sorry formatting an answer is not working as it should be but its a working code, hope it helps

Kareem, I edit your post to fix the auto format. Changes will be visible soon as someone will validate them ;) Thanks for your answer.

Thanks. I tested after paying with PayPal and success page doesn't show anything. Using Xdebug on Block/Success.php it doesn't even seem to be triggered. The module is enabled and the log files don't show any error message.

Ok, it works but there's a issue: the links showed in the success page are not "masked". I mean, the links are not like the ones received in the email like (e.g.) https://www.example.com/downloadable/download/link/id/MC4xNTUwMjcwMCAxNzI0MjI3Njc4NDI0UzI%2C/

With "masked" I meant "hashed" :D

I think should be useful the method getPurchasedLinkUrl in vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Block/Sales/Order/Email/Items/Order/Downloadable.php

However, there's another tiny issue... the links are visible either the order is set as completed or pending.

I added this so it's shown only for completed order: if ($order->getState() == \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {...}

When you land on success page after purchasing, Magento displays a message with the increment id of the new order. Since then, you have at least this information.
From that you could fetch the order and then the products ordered.
Filter them on type, looking only for downloadble once. Give them to the template for display.
Watch out : you want not do that if you have payment by check or bank transfer.
